# how to add active css class to a link in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

how to add active css class to a link in Wordpress such that the active menu li will have different color when that link is viewed.

```
<ul>
  <li class=""><a href="/news">News</a></li> 
  <li class="devider">&nbsp;</li>
  <li class=""><a href="/about">About Us</a></li> 
  <li class="devider">&nbsp;</li>
  <li><a href="#">Partners</a></li> 
  <li class="devider">&nbsp;</li> 
  <li><a href="/vacancy">Careers</a></li>  <li class="devider">&nbsp;</li>
  <li><a target="_blank" href="/webmail">Email Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the most simple way to solve it. No javascript or anything than just Wordpress

**Use it just using Wordpress built-in boolean function**

```
 <li<?php if (is_page('services')) { echo ' class="current_page_item"'; } ?>><a href="<?php echo home_url();?>/services">Services</a></li>
```

here is the link from where i got this idea.
http://www.vanseodesign.com/wordpress/hightlight-current-page-wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

the code you provided is not WordPress it`s just something you added to your "header.php" but you can try something like this for it:

```
$(function() {
  $('ul a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('active');
});
```

if you have a default WordPress menu the active class in it is called ".current-menu-item" and if you want to change it's name to let`s say ".active" find the file called "functions.php" and add this to it:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
     if( in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){
             $classes[] = 'active ';
     }
     return $classes;
}
```

Comment: No I am using HTML only I don't want to use that register menu things in functions.php  because I don't want to change the menu look and feel at all.

Comment: then try the first example .

Comment: Thanks, facing similar problem as I needed to have an active class in my wordpress theme, the second approach you provided worked for me..